# Regex to get the text from the beginning in HTML code

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find certain words in an HTML string.
The criteria are any of the followings:

- The word is in the beginning `^`.
- The word is in the middle and there is a space before it.
- The word is the in the beginning after a tag.

I am able to get the first two but failing to get the third criteria.

Example string:

```
Leading a team of 5.
You will be leading a team of 5
<span style="color:#f0f;">Leading a team of 5</span>
The code is ok
He is a good coder
```

The result should be: `[Leading, leading, Leading, He]`

My current regex:

```
/(?:^|\s)(lead[a-z]{0,}|he[\s])/gi
```

I am using replace to enrich the words, for example:

```
text.replace(regex, `<b>\$1</b>`);
```

I cannot figure out how to get the word only.

I know I can remove the `(?:^|\s)` part but this will impact small words like `he` as it will be matched with `the, The ... etc`

Comment: I don't understand the spec. "The word is in the middle and there is a space before it." applies to pretty much every word in your lines. How is it that `leading` was matched and none of the words in `The code is ok` wasn't? If you want `leading` and `he` specifically, why not match those directly? `s.replace(/\b(leading|he)\b/ig, "<b>$1</b>")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
(?:^(?:<[^>]*>)?|\s)(he|lead[a-z]*)\b
```

The pattern matches

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^(?:<[^>]*>)?` Start of string, optionally match a tag like pattern (Assuming no `>` chars before the closing `>`
  - `|` Or
  - `\s` Match a whitespace char
- `)` Close on capture group
- `(he|lead[a-z]*)` Match either `he` or `lead` followed by optional char a-z
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QjGjJY/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:^(?:<[^>]*>)?|\s)(he|lead[a-z]*)\b/gi;
[
  "Leading a team of 5.",
  "You will be leading a team of 5",
  "<span style=\"color:#f0f;\">Leading a team of 5</span>lead",
  "The code is ok",
  "He is a good coder",
  "test the lead test !@#$leadi and leading"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} ==> ${Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1])}`)
);
```